# Excel Output based on multiple input

Tags: excel, dynamic, excel-formula

I have multiple input values in excel that should be used to dynamically generate an output in a cell.

For example in cell B1:B15 I have 15 checkboxes, and in cell A1 I have a dropdown menu with multiple values. Now I want to take the value of cell A1 and then based on the checked boxes in B1:B15 I want to generate an output (a notition with an image). As you can imagine, there's quite a lot of possible ways in this 'graph'. What would be the easiest way to implement such a thing in excel, in such a manner that it is easy to expand upon?

So for example:

If (a1=="wood" and (b1==checked, b2==checked, b5==checked), "Output1")

If (a1=="wood" and (b1==checked, b5==checked, b7==checked), "Output2")

... etc.

Comment: I need a screenshot or something to help my visualise/understand what you're on about mate

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to manipulate images in excel just using formulas.

That being said, I think there might be a way to get a result similar to what you are looking for.

If you create a 2 column table of cells (I'm using c2:d5), first column checks column B for the specifics you want (ex: c2 will look at cells B1, B2, B3, and return "True" if they are all "Checked"), then all you have to do is create an output cell that says `=vlookup("True",c2:d5,2,false)`, then it will return what you put in column d next to the check in column c.

If you want a default option if none of the conditions work out, put "True" on the last line of the table, instead of another condition. Vlookup finds the first matching condition, so as long as its the last option, it will only be found if none of the rest match "True".

if you want this to happen only if A1 = "Wood", then put a If statement around it. (`=IF(A1 = "Wood", Vlookup(), [insert what you want if its not equal to "wood"])`)

If you want a physical change to the cell you typed "wood" into, you can use conditional formatting: create a custom format, choose the format, type the formula as a true/false if statement. (There may be other ways to get it to work, but I don't know of any other way to make a conditional format), EX: `=IF(AND($A$1="Wood",vlookup("True",c2:d5,2,false)=[result]),TRUE,FALSE)`